# combobox1.value does not read Numbers

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform

I have a script that works when the data is text, but does not work when its number.

Please help

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Dim iRow As Long


For iRow = 1 To 20

If UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Article").Cells(iRow, 1).Value Then
UserForm1.Label3.Caption = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Article").Cells(iRow, 2).Value
UserForm1.Label4.Caption = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Article").Cells(iRow, 4).Value

End If
If UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CRC'S").Cells(iRow, 1).Value Then
UserForm1.Label6.Caption = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CRC'S").Cells(iRow, 3).Value
End If

Next

End Sub
```

UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value is coming from that sheet as i did a properties change in Row Source.

If the data on sheet(Article) cell A1 is text this works fine. but does not work for numbers.

can anyone Please help. I am using office 2010 at work. (let me know its some add in issue)

thank you

Comment: Since .Caption expects a string, you need to cast .Value to a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
 .Caption = DirectCast(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Article").Cells(iRow, 2).Value, String)
```

or

```
.Caption = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Article").Cells(iRow, 2).Value)
```